# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined Angular Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch product title from firebase DB on HTML angular component. Date and Shipping name is working fine but product title is generating an error on console.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
      <ng-container *ngIf="orders$ | async as order">
        <ng-container *ngIf="order.payload.val().items" ; else notFound>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">Order Details</h4>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">Customer Name:</span> {{order.payload.val().shipping.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">Order Date:</span> {{order.payload.val().datePlaced | date}}
                </li>

                <li  class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">Order Title:</span> {{order.payload.val().items.product.title}}
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container> 
    </ng-container>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[Firebase DB Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBrP9.png)

Comment: can you add content of your order object to your question please.

Comment: I just want to know the correct code to fetch the product title kindly check the firebase db tree structure in the given image..date and shipping name is getting display but product title isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your items is an array therefore you will have to use the following to get the title of the item. (items[0])

```
<li  class="list-group-item">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">Order Title:</span> {{order.payload.val().items[0].product.title}}
</li>
```

if you want to display all items you can use *ngFor directive

```
<li  *ngFor="let item of order.payload.val().items; let i = index"  class="list-group-item">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">Order Title:</span> {{item.product.title}}
</li>
```

Comment: It works, but what for the other items like if items has more than 1 array? I want to display all available items data in order details.